# How can I map over my data set and set a single variable to an objects name?

Tags: reactjs, search, filter, components

I have a data set of objects.  When my component mounts it receives an argument from the command line - I would like to scan my data set for this argument and set a variable to a matched objects file name.

PropTypes...

```
Landing.propTypes = {
   data: PropTypes.arrayOf(
           PropTypes.object
   )
}

Landing.defaultProps = {
   data: HelpData
}
```

When my component mounts...

```
componentWillMount() {
   let tstTitle = 'SearchForThisMatch'
   let tstFile = '';

   // goal is to search my data set for 'SearchForThisMatch' and set tstFile to obj.file

let menuOpen = this.props.data.filter(obj => {
      return this.props.name === obj.name;
        }).map((obj, idx) => {
          return (
            <div key={idx}>
              {obj.file}
             </div>
          );
     });

}
```

Currently I'm returning a div with the obj.file name in it.  All I really want to do is set a variable to the obj.file's name - which is a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just set the variable inside the `map` function:

```
componentWillMount() {
   let tstTitle = 'SearchForThisMatch'
   let tstFile = '';

   // goal is to search my data set for 'SearchForThisMatch' and set tstFile to obj.file

let menuOpen = this.props.data.filter(obj => {
      return this.props.name === obj.name;
        }).map((obj, idx) => {
          //HERE <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
          tstFile = obj.file;
          return (
            <div key={idx}>
              {obj.file}
             </div>
          );
     });

}
```

Comment: And I will have access to tstFile outside of menuOpen?  I don't want to use the return div, so it will just be discarded?

Comment: I should also change return this.props.name to tstTtitle === obj.name